# IIS 8.5 Two websites, one in subfolder of the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-8.5

## Situation

- I have two websites, let's call them MAIN and SVC (a SOAP service).
- Both are written in ASP.NET MVC.
- They are hosted on (e.g.) https://prog.example.com.

## What I want

- MAIN should be reachable as https://prog.example.com
- SVC's service should be reachable as https://prog.example.com/svc/myservice.svc (=> a subfolder of MAIN)

## My problem

I can get this to work, if MAIN is reachable as https://prog.example.com/main, so that both URLs are distinct. When SVC is a sub-URL from MAIN (see what I want), it isn't reachable anymore. My code of the service fails, because it cannot find some classes anymore.

## Current situation

Site with two sub-apps (main, svc) works, but MAIN has the subfolder /main. When I point the site directly to the folder of MAIN (without the sub-app), MAIN is reachable as desired, but SVC throws the exception as mentioned in my problem.

How can I configure IIS, that my service still works, when the main website is directly reachable without a subfolder like /main?

I had the idea of keeping MAIN in /main, but redirecting the basic url to /main. This resulted in a loop of /main/main/main/main/...

It is not possible to use e.g. https://prog.example.com and https://service.example.com (so that the binding could differ by subdomain).

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible. You just add SVC as a virtual application under your MAIN site in IIS.

The only thing to bear in mind is that Web.config files are inherited, so any application under MAIN will inherit MAIN's Web.config, in addition to its own. This often results in conflicts. You'll either need to resolve said conflicts or disable inheritance on any sections of MAIN's Web.config that causing issues. For example:

```
<connectionStrings inheritInChildApplications="false">
    ...
</connectionStrings>
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to simply disable inheritance for the entire Web.config, so you have to do this on a node-by-node basis.